# Deploy service to Google Play

Tags: android, google-play

I would like to create a service (let's call it `Service A`) that runs on Android and is used by 3rd party applications (let's call one of these applications `Application B`). Such a solution would be similar to [`Google Play Services for AR`](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core&hl=en).

I'm trying to understand how to create the dependency between `Application B`, and `Service A` on the store, such that when installing `Application B`, `Service A` is also installed.

To return to the `Google Play Services for AR` example, as a 3rd party app developer, I just have to specify a dependency to the `ARCore` library, and when I install the app on a device, the service is also installed.

The reason I want to do this is to be able to update `Service A` independently of updates to `Application B`, as the release cycle of `Application B` is not under my control.

Comment: There's a Google Play Services _app_ (which typically comes pre-installed on your phone). Third-party apps using Google Play Services do so through client libraries which interact with the Google Play Services app (see https://developers.google.com/android/guides/overview).

Comment: @Michael I also stumbled over the `Google Play Services`, with the many libraries referencing it. My question is how to implement something like `Google Play Services`, that does something else. E.g.: a service that provides the nth digit of pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to `create the dependency between Application B, and Service A` You can definitely utilize the [uses-library](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-library-element) Manifest tag to prevent people from downloading it from the store without your custom dependency being on their device, but this will only prevent them from obtaining it from the store; they could still download it a myriad of other ways.

Your best bet would be to have your application launch to a specific launch activity that checks if the package exists on their device:

```
    public static boolean doesUseHaveMyDependency(Context context){
        try{
            context.getPackageManager().getApplicationInfo("com.yourlib.package", 0 );
            return true;
        } catch( PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e ){
            return false;
        }
    }
```

With that, you can determine if your custom library is installed. If not, simply redirect them to the download link to obtain it, then when they reopen the app you check again. Once you have confirmed that they have it, you can progress to the main application.